# Unable to publish a Referenced Mosaic Dataset to ArcGIS Server 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, mosaic-dataset, arcgis-image-server

I have a number of Raster Catalogs I want to publish.  It is my understanding that in order for them to be published to ArcGIS Server I need to create Referenced Mosaic Datasets for them.

I have done this.

I have also successfully registered the data folders with ArcGIS Server and enabled the Image extension (this is needed to publish mosaics).

When I come to publish the referenced mosaic dataset, in the Service Editor I select to only use the “Image” capability and for it to only allow the “image” operation, as I only want the user to be able to view the data.  I am not caching the service.

When I analyse the service, I only get one Medium error.  This is just warning me that no statistics have been calculated for the Mosaic dataset.  As this service is a “view-only” service, I do not need statistics.

When I click on “Publish”, it runs through the whole publishing service and then I get an error

> Failed to Publish Service.

If I look at the server log, I get the following error:

> Error executing tool.: ERROR 001369: Failed to create the service.
>   Failed to execute (Publish Service Definition)

This seems to be a generic error.

Digging a bit more into the server log I can see that there is an error about an invalid path:

> Invalid input data source path:
>   \\servername\data\Production\Backdrop_Mapping\Mosaics\Data_50K\Data_50K.gdb\Data_50K

This is refering to the Mosaic dataset which I am trying to publish.

This folder is successfully registered as a data store on the server:

> \\servername\data\Production\Backdrop_Mapping

As I understand it, this should include all subfolders.

I have created a simple mxd with 1 vector dataset and published it from the same source folder without any problems.  The vector dataset was in the same fgdb as the mosaic dataset.  So I know the server is able to connect to and read from this location.

Any sugestions of what I could try next would be great.

Tech spec:  ArcGIS Sever 10.2.1, Standard Licence, Image extension.

Comment: It was my understanding that data store registration is at the geodatabase level.  What happens when you register  down to Data_50K.gdb?

Comment: With the current setup I am able to publish raster images and vector datasets stored in the Data_50K.gdb It is just the eferenced Mosaic Datasets that fail. But I will try now just in case Ref Mosaic Datasets behave differently. Thanks

Comment: did you find an answer ? I have the same error for publishing a service with raster data after upgrading to ArcGIS 10.3.1.
https://geonet.esri.com/message/529471#529471 Please let me know if you have any useful information. Regards Hilde

Comment: I created mosaic datasets rather than referenced mosaic datasets.  This published seamlessly.  You should really post your "answer" to my question as a new question, as per the forum guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

In ArcCatalog, go to the referenced mosaic dataset you are unable to load. Right click; go to Modify; from the pull out menu, select Repair. Notice the Original Path. This is the error: the path is not what your server can see. Even if it looks right, do this: In ArcCatalog, select the Raster Catalog that the reference mosaic dataset was created from. Copy the path to that Raster Catalog from ArcCatalog. Paste it as the New Path in the Repair tool. Hit OK. If you get an error, check the New Path in comparison to the Original Path to ensure it is complete. For example, it is not enough to copy a path to the fgdb only. The path must include the Raster Catalog as well. Once repaired, your ArcGIS server should be able to use them without errors.